# How to make a call to the server when filtering react-multi-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, multi-select, react-select-search

I need to make a request to the server each time user types in the `Multiselect` input to retrieve data based on the search query.

If i set the list with fixed values it works fine and filter the list.

```
import MultiSelect from "react-multi-select-component";
...


const options = [
    { label: "Grapes ", value: "grapes" },
    { label: "Mango ", value: "mango" },
    { label: "Strawberry ", value: "strawberry" },
];

const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

<MultiSelect
    options={options}
    value={selected}
    onChange={setSelected}
    labelledBy={"Select"}
/>
```

I tried to use `filterOptions` `props` on the `MultiSelect`. The problem is that when i press on the `MultiSelect` and start typing in the input it keeps making calls to the sever until I clear the value of the MultiSelect input. it stopped.

```
const [invoices,set_invoices] = useState([]);
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

function test(options, filter) {
    if (!filter) {
        return options;
    }
    var data={'invoice_number':'22'}
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/get_invoice_by_number',data).then(
        response => {
            // The for loop below is to make the invoices objects like 
            // {label:'',value:''}
            var temp_invoices=[];
            for(var i =0;i<response.data.length;i++){
                temp_invoices.push({
                    label:response.data[i].invoice_number,
                    value:response.data[i].invoice_number
                })
            }
            // JSON.stringify(temp_invoices)
            set_invoices(temp_invoices);

        },error =>{
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Error!',
                text: 'Please Contact your software developer',
                icon: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'OK'
            })
        }
    )
    return options;
}

<MultiSelect
    options={invoices}
    value={selected}
    labelledBy={"Select"}
    onChange={setSelected}
    filterOptions={test}
/>
```

Comment: Where do you call the `search_list` function?

Comment: @Esther-I on `MultiSelect` onChange props, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `filterOptions` props MultiSelect component.
The functions passed in the props will be triggered when user types in the `Multiselect` input.

But the `onChange` will be triggered only on selection of options.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MultiSelect from "react-multi-select-component";

const Example: React.FC = () => {
  const options = [];
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = e => {
   // Triggered for option select
  }
  function filterOptions(options, filter) {
    // Triggered for filter input changes
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(selected)}</pre>
      <MultiSelect
        options={options}
        value={selected}
        onChange={handleChange}
        labelledBy={"Select"}
        filterOptions={filterOptions}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me, but i think i am far one step from the answer, I Updated the question with after i applied `filterOptions` but got error is that as long as the value of the `MultiSelect` not empty it keeps on making calls to the server, but when i clear the value it stopped.

Comment: I think the problem is because of  `set_invoices(temp_invoices)' as it is leading to re render the component